# Putting the \chapter in main .tex file or inside included files?

Tags: chapters, best-practices, include

What is the usual way of making chapters when working with large `.tex` files?

Do you put `\chapter{Chapter 1}` inside the main `.tex` file, or in the included files?

What is the norm, and are there any differences or advantages of doing it one way or another?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\input{Chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Or do you put `\chapter{Chapter 1}` inside the `Chapter1.tex` separate file?

Comment: I usually put it inside the file, and use `\include` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include for the difference from `\input`).

Comment: like @TorbjørnT, i put the `\chapter` line inside the `chapterx.tex` file and use `\include`.  but i often put a commented-out copy of that `\chapter` line in the driver file, to help me remember what i'm doing, and if i have to make any special adjustments to that chapter, like add an `\addtocontents` line, i also put *that* in the `chapterx.tex` file and a comment in the driver file. comments are good things.

Comment: I am aware of `\include` vs `\input` thing, but I was wondering if there is a big difference on putting chapter in or out of the included file.
The only valid difference I found is with `\appendix`, where I'll get different result on defining it outside the inputted file...

Comment: Thanks on the advices, especially about commenting, it's really a good practice to do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a book or a thesis, which usually has more than one chapter it is a -- in my opinion -- very good strategy to write an central dokument, including document class, praeambel (perhaps an own file), `\begin{document}`, the chapters, each in one file (names like `preface.tex`, `ìntroduction.tex`, `conclusion.tex`. Do **not** use `chapter1.tex` or `3.tex` etc. because it could happen you have to change the order of your chapters). Make the central document understandable at once.

Each chapter file includes the hole chapter **including** chapter heading!

If you use `\include{introduction}` you can not forget to start a new chapter on a new (or right) side, because `\include`  does it for you.

So the central document should be:

```
\documentclass[options]{documentclass}
\input{praeambel.tex}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % if book or scrbook
\include{preface} % starts on new page!
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter % if book or scrbook
\include{introduction}
% ...

\end{document}
```

and the file `intrduction.tex` contains:

```
\chapter{Introduction}%
\label{sec:introduction} 

the chapter text ...
```

and so on.

Just keep things together which belong together and devide (build logical units) were it is possible.

Comment: Great answer :) I'll keep this in mind :) Oh and chapter stuff was just an example, I'm making my sections like you said, with specific names :)

Comment: Additionally, if your want to use an "Inverse Search"-Feature (i.e. you double-click the PDF to get to the LaTeX-Source of what you clicked), it makes sense to put the \chapter in the included file. At least I prefer to get to the included file, if I click on the headings.